# Beta reduction exercise question

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am trying to reduce the following $\lambda$-expression:
$$(\lambda x.x x) (\lambda y.y x) z$$
So I am reducing to
$$(\lambda y.y x) (\lambda y.y x) z$$
That reduces to
$$(\lambda y.y x)xz$$
Now comes trouble. According to the solution given [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2011/cmsc330/prac5-solutions.pdf) at letter k, you have:
$$ (\lambda y.y x)xz \rightsquigarrow_\beta xxz$$
Bout from what I understand it should be:
$$ (\lambda y.y x)xz \rightsquigarrow_\beta xzx$$
Because the lambda expression $(\lambda y.y x)$ just adds a final $x$ to the term that it is applied to.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, the lambda expression $(\lambda y.yx)$ just adds a final $x$ to the term it's applied to.  In the case at hand, it's applied to $x$, not to $xz$.  Applying it to $x$ produces $xx$ while the $z$ at the end just sits there.

Remember the standard convention of lambda calculus that $abc$ means $(ab)c$, not $a(bc)$.  That's why, in $(\lambda y.yx)xz$, the $(\lambda y.yx)$ is applied only to the $x$, not to the $xz$.